# Problemas de ingtegracion Mercado Envios y Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de integrar Mercado Envíos en mi tienda  hecha con Wordpress + Woocommerce + Modulo oficial Mercadopago.
Tengo instada la ultima version del plugin , ya configure los ajustes de Checkout Básico, con los datos de api y demás, tambien configure la opción de envíos en woocommerce activando mercado envíos normal y mercado envíos express.

Al hacer la prueba en modo Sandbox como dice el tutorial de MP para que me pasen a modo producción, usando el numero de tarjeta ficticia 4444 4444 4444 0008,  al final me devuelve la siguiente pantalla que dice:

**Debes autorizar ante visa el pago de $ 274,99  a Mercado Pago**

Y el pago aparentemente nuca queda concretado.
¿Esta bien que la prueba en modo Sandbox usando un sitio con Woocommerce, devuelva ese mensaje de autorizacion?

Graciasl

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tambien de paso mira [Por que no somos soporte de Mercado pago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%c3%a9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%c3%b1%c3%ada-favorita)

Comment: Listo editada !!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me pasó. Revisá que los productos tengan peso y dimensiones, para que pueda ser calculado por el plugin de Mercado Envíos. Además, que la opción "Mercado Envíos" esté activada desde la configuración de tu cuenta de Mercado Pago.